# Typescript, map types from object to tuple

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Consider the following interface:

```js
interface Theme {
  color: {
    primary: {
      light: string
      base: string
      dark: string
    }
    secondary: {
      lighter: string
      light: string
      base: string
      dark: string
      darker: string
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to write a type that will allow a tuple, the first element mapped to any key in `colors`, and the second mapped to any key under that (ie: `base`).

ie:

```
['primary', 'light'] ✅ valid
['secondary', 'darker'] ✅ valid
['primary', 'darker']  invalid
```

Here is an attempt i've made on [tsplayground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=17&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoAsIFsUG8BQyyCA9gDYlQBcyBRRADlMFnFAJ4131FnADm6MDQDOYZiH6EeyAEZwREUeNBSZyACZsA1solr6AX2lFFpEFo5cT9PoMjVkY-Td4Che1a7kKlTlZLelrr%20LurB0J6BPMZExsb4YOwMKAAKwAjaGNgQAMLklAA8ucgQAB6QFiLI2hDsJDBomDgA2gDkpBRQbQC6yAC8NXUNTTntnZS9AHwDyC3SuQA00rX1jdmtHQXdPS25PfgH%20AD0x8iAvBuA4juAPBuAP-vIYOjA1aRYDGRwoNWyEAhwAK6KZBtCLdTQkCAicDIOAMFJsZCgOQkR7ApgsNjsNowizAswkCyY7GrET4fDmMTIMo0dKZDZ5baFNro1gcbEAHzxvwJlixM0G7XxhLZi2BoN6QA) the problem i'm facing here is that if i want to allow multiple keys to be passed as the first arg, then second needs to satisfy all of the firsts. Is there a way to tell typescript to use the literal value passed as the type?

```
type PickThemeColor<C extends keyof Theme['color'] = keyof Theme['color']> = [
  C,
  keyof Theme['color'][C]
]

//  this complains because 'darker' doesnt appear in both 'primary' and 'secondary' keys

const x: PickThemeColor<'primary' | 'secondary'> = ['secondary', 'darker']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you were very close. The only missing thing was distributing color key:

```
type ColorKey = keyof Theme['color'];
type ShadeKey<K extends ColorKey> = keyof Theme['color'][K];

type PickThemeColor<C extends ColorKey> = C extends ColorKey ? [C, ShadeKey<C>] : never;

const x1: PickThemeColor<'primary' | 'secondary'> = ['primary', 'light'] // OK
const x2: PickThemeColor<'primary' | 'secondary'> = ['secondary', 'darker'] // OK
const x3: PickThemeColor<'primary' | 'secondary'> = ['primary', 'darker'] // Error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoAsIFsUG8BQyyCA9gDYlQBcyBRRADlMFnFAJ4131FnADm6MDQDOYZiH6EeyAEZwREUeNBSZyACZsA1solr6AX2lFFpEFo5cT9PoMjVkY-Td4Che1a7kKlTlZLelrr+LurB0J6BPMZExsb4YOwMKADC5JQA0hDsyAC8yNo5JDBomDgA2gDkpBRQVQC6ANyJySgAyuhwGhDZ7AA8mcgQAB6QFiLI6XV9AHz5hcWlGNgQ1bWUjRWZzfitKcgACsAI2is405T9qcNjEBNTGVBzCzej4xqTl885yAD8yAqqQANMhOt1ejlrrMGsgaCAIAA3aAtfDmMTIEYARhox1O5wg336VSYLDY7CqyAAPsgqmYSBZyVV5gVqqTWBwqqCqnYhI1kAB6AXIADymTRDIxIwATLiTmdyoSnsT2UzqbT6YzOSzAXSIOZLBTuRF6rChaLxeiwJiAMxy-GKokk5gcinqvUGpk6tkupnGnTQfnmgCiUCglCAA)

---

`ColorKey` and `ShadeKey` where extracted just to simplify `PickThemeColor` (nothing new here). What makes the difference is `C extends ColorKey` part as it [distributes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#distributive-conditional-types) over union of color keys.

So `PickThemeColor<'primary'>` will produce
`["primary", "light" | "base" | "dark"]`

And `PickThemeColor<'primary' | 'secondary'>` will produce
`["primary", ShadeKey<"primary">] | ["secondary", ShadeKey<"secondary">]`

Comment: Thanks! this looks great. Im still seeing the same as above where my intellisense for the second tuple value always suggests *all* possible values (instead of valid ones based on the first argument) - is this possible?

Comment: Not sure regarding intellisense, but type checking works as expected as you can see

Answer (score 3):

You have here 2 options, a generic, which you need to specify unfortunately or a union:

```js
// A generic way
type Typle<K extends keyof Theme['color']> = [K, keyof Theme['color'][K]];

const test1: Typle<'primary'> = ['primary', 'light'];
const test2: Typle<'secondary'> = ['secondary', 'darker'];
const test3: Typle<'primary'> = ['primary', 'darker']; // fails

// A union way.
type Typle2 <K = keyof Theme['color']> = K extends keyof Theme['color'] ? [K, keyof Theme['color'][K]] : never;

const test4: Typle2 = ['primary', 'light'];
const test5: Typle2 = ['secondary', 'darker'];
const test6: Typle2 = ['primary', 'darker']; // fails
```

---

Otherwise you need a creation function to avoid the required generic value.

```js
// a helper function way.
const craeteType = <K extends keyof Theme['color']>(v: Typle<K>): Typle<K> => {
  return v;
}

const test7 = craeteType(['primary', 'light']);
const test8 = craeteType(['secondary', 'darker']);
const test9 = craeteType(['primary', 'darker']); // fails
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoAsIFsUG8BQyyCA9gDYlQBcyBRRADlMFnFAJ4131FnADm6MDQDOYZiH6EeyAEZwREUeNBSZyACZsA1solr6AX2lFFpEFo5cT9PoMjVkY-Td4Che1a7kKlTlZLelrr+LurB0J6BPMZExsYA9AnIAILI-BAg0MAIyADucOz4YOwMKKilZBAAPADSyBAAHpAWIsjaEOwkMGiYOADaAOSkFFCDALoAfMgAvMj9tQA07Z3dvdgQQyOUEwvj4wDc+PjmYsiQYgCMNBUMVdWDTCxs7IPTc0NPrByDy4N2QgmR1OYHOEDEACYbpUaoMzCQLC83rN5nCIOZLK8-hExocTgizhcwABmaF3WFfJHvVGUn7YnTQIHIJLIeDAMgiY4stIAVxAwAR+UKADpiqVyjCIcg6iiOl0ehgNltyDspij6k0Who2nK1oqBsMVbjkAB+eZLFby9YG7a4vbjZA0LIAN2gR3xIEJ4LAABYyVUpR9HsxvljkP93GAgR6vWIAKz+iCB1HwxF08M46MgsFiABsieTnxDSPpUA6uIOzOSbI5XOScGQmDIZSgrL5CDAApAQvYouzCCgcAgkFuKDmMs1mW1lr1fU2htGE0mAApnYm6pMAJTr2rvabcKDDnlQbvOo7GGOgokAdhRA6HI-Fy6Lz3TEfsE03wIJV+9AA470HYcIFHZ80QxEsMwZXEv0vHMwAATkAh8QKfF9Q1+KCy0ZcYvyrVk4HZTkgA)

Comment: Thanks! one thing, my intellisense is suggesting all possible values for the second argument instead of restricting them to keys of the first, is there a way around this? 

Comment: Ah, then I think we need to remove `= keyof Theme['color']` and always to set it in `: Typle<>`. I've updated the answer.